# How to get date in UTC format irrespective of current system date with javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am trying to get the current date in UTC format. SO far I am able to do it but what I am stuck with is that it checks for the current 'System Date' and returns the result. I do not want that to happen because I need it specifically in UTC format and not by getting the system date.

Also, the format I have output the result is the one I want with no changes in it. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Here is my code:

```
var now = new Date();
var currentDate;
var date = (new Date(now) + '').split(' ');
date[0] = date[0] + ',';
date[2] = date[2] + ',';
currentDate = [date[0], date[1], date[2], date[3]].join(' ');
return currentDate;
```

This returns as Wed, Apr26, 2016. If this code is run somewhere else with a time difference of say +-12, the date will be that system date in UTC which I do not want.

Comment: UTC is not a format, it's a [*time standard*](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html). The only standardised Date formatting available is *toISOString*, all other formatting is implementation dependant. There are small formatting libraries, like [*date-format.js*](https://github.com/barbir/js-date-format/blob/master/js/date-format.js), or much larger ones like [*moment.js*](http://momentjs.com/). You have not stated a format, nor why the current system date doesn't suit.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to keep the formatting consistent across browsers is to either build a small utility function using the `Date#getUTC*` functions or use a library that does this for you. I would go with the former. You could use something like this:

```
function getUTCDateString(){
    var d = new Date();
    var days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
    var month  = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    return (
        days[d.getUTCDay()-1]
        + ', ' + month[d.getUTCMonth()]
        + d.getUTCDate() 
        + ', ' + d.getUTCFullYear()
        );
}
```

If you do any localized programming things quickly increase in complexity and bringing in some of the libs mentioned makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the output you mentioned, check this out:

```
var dateString = new Date().toUTCString().split(' ');
return dateString[0] + " " + dateString[2] + dateString[1] + ", " + dateString[3];
```

There are some other useful UTC methods for Dates [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString).

Comment: Given that [*toUTCString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring) is implementation dependent, the resulting string might be anything.

Comment: ["The format of the return value may vary according to the platform. The most common return value is a RFC-1123 formatted date stamp, which is a slightly updated version of RFC-822 date stamps."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)

Comment: @oligofren—MDN is a public wiki, it is not a language authority. Per [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring) (which is **the** authority): "*The contents of the String are implementation-dependent, but are intended to represent this time value in a convenient, human-readable form in UTC*". It goes on to recommend ISO 8601 extended format (though in a non–normative note).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into momentjs? It's a date object wrapper that makes manipulating dates easy. Just use the utc() function provided. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/

After installing moment through npm, here's what sample code will look like:

```
var moment = require("moment");

 var utcNow = moment().utc();

 console.log(utcNow);
```

This will output current utc date

Comment: No, no, no. This is like every javascript question on StackOverflow 7 years ago, where every question was answered with how to do this in jQuery. Just learn javascript. While MomentJS is a nice lib, it means half a MB of JS to download and parse for your users, and you never include a whole lib for just one utility function. You should only ever do that if you write your whole project in ES2015 and use a bundler such as Rollup that will only include the bits that are used.

Comment: @oligofren—and I thought I was the only one writing comments like that! Of course `new Date().toISOString()` will do much the same without a library.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new too! Just trying to do my part in the community with what I know. In every instance that I've worked with dates so far I've had to use them throughout large projects so it was never an issue to include a helpful library. Thanks for the tip and I'll remember that next time!

Comment: @Cameron637: sorry if that came off a bit blunt. At times, the tone can be a bit harsh on SO, so please keep on contributing! Of course one can use libraries, but one should always remember they come with a cost. The bigger the project, the more important this becomes. Remember that copy-paste is also reuse :-) As mentioned, this picture is changing somewhat due to new tools using ES2015, that only includes the code that actually being used,

Comment: If the poster needs to actually output products in a local format, perhaps doing time calculations across zones, I would absolutely not roll my own solution and rather use Moment, as time and date calculations are notoriously hard to get right with all the local details - no matter the language.

Comment: @oligofren—but most time and date calculations require some significant business input for rules (e.g. what is "end of month", how long is a month, how to add a month, what is the first day of the week, what is a quarter, etc.) that is often defined by financial or reporting rules or packages, a library doesn't help with any of that. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend calling the `toISOString()` method on the date instance. Here's the code

```
var now = new Date,
    isoNow = now.toISOString();
console.log(now, isoNow); // Wed Apr 27 2016 10:50:29 GMT+0530 (IST) "2016-04-27T05:20:29.146Z"
```

So you have universal time here